# ImageMagick with MAMP 4 - mac mojave

Tags: php, imagemagick, mamp, php-7, imagick

I am trying to install ImageMagick for MAMP 4.

My php version is: 7.1.19
I went to `applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.12/conf/php.ini`
and changed this line `;extension=imagick.so` to `extension=imagick.so`. 
I also have a php folder in there of `php7.2.1` so I did the above change there too. I restarted MAMP.

After doing that phpinfo told me that ImageMagick is present:

[image]

However when I try to run a line of code like this:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$im = new Imagick("test.png");
```

I received the error `localhost is unable to handle this request`, if I remove these lines of code then the page loads fine.

I have also installed ImageMagick, `imagemagick 7.0.8-14 is already installed and up-to-date`.

Comment: You need to tell PHP that the Imagick namespace is built-in with a back slash: `$im = new \Imagick("test.png");`   Note back slash before Imagick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)